# How to input values into a html form in python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I have a simple html form, like this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/Login/Authenticate" id="Loginform" method="post">
  <label for="fname">User name:</label><br>
  <input class="Txt_bx password" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter Password" id="txtPassword" name="Log.password" type="text"><br>
  <label for="lname">Password :</label><br>
  <input class="Txt_bx urserName" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter Username" id="txtusername" name="Log.username" type="password" value="">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to insert some text into the input class `Txt_bx password` and `Txt_bx username` without using selenium as it is too slow. Is there any other way I can do this?

Any help would be Appreciated!

Comment: dear @Heisenberg why didn't use jquery or js? and is this for testing? sorry for my language because English isn't my primary language

Comment: @sachinkumaraliyanage because I don't know jquery and js. I wanted to hack a simple html form using python, that's why I'm learning how to do so but I couldn't find how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library for Python, and [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp) should help to introduce you to `POST` (as seen by the `method` tag on the form) requests in the library. You will need to POST to `/Login/Authenticate`, as it is the `action` of the form.

In your HTML code, `log.Password` and `log.Username` will be the dictionary's keys, and the values will be whatever values you want. For example:

```
data = {
    "log.Username": "mynewusername",
    "log.Password": "mynewpassword"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this. Also, sorry for asking such an easy searchable question, I'm bad at googling.

Comment: are you sure the OP doesn't mean input text INTO the input fields?

Comment: @TochiBedford I don't know what the code does, since I can't seem to run that properly, but I do mean to get to get the text into the input fields and submit it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using Requests

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
    'http://url.com/Login/Authenticate',
    data={
        "Log.password": "password",
        "Log.username": "username"
    }

)

print(response.content) #get the response from whatever server
```

Don't forget to replace url.com with the actual domain